# Parallel execution of jobs using coroutines

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to execute multiple jobs in parallel using coroutines. This is the piece of code that I came up with.
I have 2 queries:

- How do I ensure completion callbacks happen in the caller thread?
- Code has become more like the callback pattern I used to have with
  normal threads. Please suggest changes in design to achieve the
  coroutines readability advantage.

```
class ParallelExecutor {

    suspend fun <OUTPUT> execute(
        jobs: List<suspend () -> OUTPUT>,
        onTimeout: (jobIndex: Int) -> OUTPUT,
        onFailure: (jobIndex: Int, exception: Throwable) -> OUTPUT,
        onCompletion: suspend (jobIndex: Int, result: OUTPUT) -> Unit,
        timeout: Long,
        onFullCompletion: suspend () -> Unit = {},
        invokeDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default
    ) {
        withContext(invokeDispatcher) {
            var counter = 0
            val listenJobs = mutableListOf<Deferred<OUTPUT>>()

            jobs.forEachIndexed { index, job ->
                val listenJob = async {

                    try {
                        job()
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        onFailure(index, e)
                    }
                }
                listenJobs.add(listenJob)
            }

            listenJobs.forEachIndexed { index, job ->
                launch {
                    val output = try {
                        withTimeout(timeout) {
                            job.await()
                        }
                    } catch (e: TimeoutCancellationException) {
                        onTimeout(index)
                    }
                    onCompletion(index, output)
                    if (++counter == listenJobs.size) {
                        onFullCompletion()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a very ... different way of using coroutines, are you sure you want to use coroutines to do that? I don't think this needs to be this generic.

Comment: How is this function being used in your code? That'll make it easier to make suggestions.

Comment: You want the completion callbacks called in the "caller thread" or the "caller dispatcher"? (Thread might not be possible).

Comment: @DominicFischer I have few places where I want to start multiple identical jobs in parallel. This piece of code was redundant at all these places. So I moved it outside. Thats how I reached at this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to me that you can simplify your code quite a bit. You don't need a two-step idiom that first launches all the `async` jobs and then launches more jobs to await on them. You can just `launch` the jobs and delegate to the callbacks within the same block. That way the callbacks will naturally be invoked on the caller's dispatcher and only the job itself can be called within the changed context with the `invokeDispatcher`.

`onFullCompletion` looks like a piece of code that belongs on the caller side, below the `execute` call. Since `execute` doesn't throw any exceptions, you don't need any `try-finally` to get it.

```
suspend fun <OUTPUT> execute(
    jobs: List<suspend () -> OUTPUT>,
    onTimeout: (jobIndex: Int) -> OUTPUT,
    onFailure: (jobIndex: Int, exception: Throwable) -> OUTPUT,
    onCompletion: suspend (jobIndex: Int, result: OUTPUT) -> Unit,
    timeout: Long,
    invokeDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default
) {
    coroutineScope {
        jobs.mapIndexed { index, job ->
            launch {
                val output = try {
                    withTimeout(timeout) {
                        withContext(invokeDispatcher) {
                            job()
                        }
                    }
                } catch (e: TimeoutCancellationException) {
                    onTimeout(index)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    onFailure(index, e)
                }
                onCompletion(index, output)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Made some improvements that should answer your queries.

```
class ParallelExecutor {

    suspend fun <OUTPUT> execute(
        jobs: List<suspend () -> OUTPUT>,
        onTimeout: (jobIndex: Int) -> OUTPUT,
        onFailure: (jobIndex: Int, exception: Throwable) -> OUTPUT,
        onCompletion: suspend (jobIndex: Int, result: OUTPUT) -> Unit,
        timeout: Long,
        invokeDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Default
    ) {
        supervisorScope {
            val listenJobs = jobs.map { job ->
                async(invokeDispatcher) {
                    withTimeout(timeout) {
                        job()
                    }
                }
            }

            listenJobs.forEachIndexed { index, job ->
                launch {
                    val output = try {
                        job.await()
                    } catch (e: TimeoutCancellationException) {
                        onTimeout(index)
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        onFailure(index, e)
                    }
                    onCompletion(index, output)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Jobs are now cancelled when timeout is reached.
- Completion callbacks are now called in the caller's **dispatcher**.
- The race condition when deciding when to call `onFullCompletion` has been fixed.
- Removed some methods that you didn't really need.

If you feel this is more like the callback pattern, then you simply shouldn't use callbacks. Coroutines are designed such that you write this sort of code at use site with minimal boilerplate, so functions like this aren't necessary and look weird (IMHO).

Comment: Thank you. I actually want the onFullCompletion callback. So the consumers don't have to decide when all the jobs are fully done. They can just pass their cleanup logic as a parameter. I was worried of the race condition and was trying to guard the counter with a lock after I posted the question.

Comment: Initially I put `onFullCompletion` at the end of the function but I thought that was pointless, since the one could just have it outside the function and save the allocation.

Comment: You can just place your clean up logic after the function call, coroutine scopes wait for the all coroutines in them to finish before returning. (Unless you really just want callback style code).

Comment: I don;t expect the consumers to handle exceptions from their code. I would also like to retain onFailure so that the consumer's  unhandled exceptions are thrown and this onFailure will force them to handle that case by making it mandatory. They can either return default values for OUTPUT or model their output like Either<Error, ACTUAL_OUTPUT>

Comment: Update to use `onFailure`.